# get X and Y of a tile on a tileset

Tags: javascript, math, canvas, game-engine, tile

I'm trying to write a function that returns the position of a tile on a tileset.

I wrote some code for that but that seems unnecessarily complicated.

how each tile has a number:

[image: img]

```js
// My old code:

    function getXPosByNumber(width, height, tilesize, tilenumber) {
    if ((tilenumber % (width / tilesize) - 1) < 0) {
        return width - tilesize;
    } else {
        return (tilenumber % (width / tilesize) - 1) * tilesize;
    }
}

function getYPosByNumber(width, height, tilesize, tilenumber) {
    return (Math.ceil(tilenumber / (width / tilesize)) - 1) * tilesize;
}
```

How can I access any tile coordonates with a cleaner/simpler code ?

Thanks.

Comment: What is `tilenumber`? Can you draw a picture with the tiles labeled by their `tilenumber`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I figured out to simplify. I found that height isn't so relevant to calculate either X or Y. The important factor here is how much it spreads horizontally.

Then, since a specific tileset will more likely always have the same width and tilesize, I suggest a more "Object"-ified approach so you don't have to constantly remember its configuration. Personally, I like to wrap constants and configurations so I can write lightweight code afterwards:

```
var tileset = function(width, tilesize) {
    this.width = width;
    this.tilesize = tilesize;
};

// calculate X by tilenumber
tileset.prototype.getX = function(tilenumber) {
    return (tilenumber % this.width - 1) * this.tilesize;
};

// calculate Y by tilenumber
tileset.prototype.getY = function(tilenumber) {
    return Math.floor(tilenumber / this.width) * this.tilesize;
};
```

That allows you to use it like this:

```
var mySet = new tileset(6, 10); // width=6, tilesize=10
var x = mySet.getX(16); // tilenumber=16
var y = mySet.getY(16); // tilenumber=16
```

To see it in action, check this [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/0arg6xx5/).

Please note that it calculates the position of top left corner. It can be adjusted otherwise if needed.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If this tileset is always the same I would suggest to create a kind of lookup table. An object that will store precalculated positions for each tile number. It will be much simpler and faster since you only need to access property of an object.